# HTML href >link text</a> is different from browser "tab title"

Tags: html, css, pdf

I have the following code

```
<div class="content">
<p>
<a href="./Arbeitszeugnisse.pdf">Arbeitszeugnisse.pdf</a>
</p>
</div>
```

where `content` looks like this

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">
  .content {
    width: 35%;
    float: left;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px solid #8511ae;
    margin-top: 0%;
    margin-bottom: 0%;
    margin-left: 2%;
    margin-right: 3%;
    background-color: #faf9d8;
}
</style>
</head>
```

When clicking on the link, the **tab title used to be** `Arbeitszeugnisse.pdf`.
After adding a page to the Arbeitszeugnisse.pdf with `PDF Arranger 1.4.2` under `Ubuntu 20.04.4` and replacing existing file with the new one, the tab title now prints

```
Layout 1 - Arbeitszeugnisse.pdf
```

Similarly I have

```
<a href="./Bildungsweg.pdf">Bildungsweg.pdf</a>
```

Bildungsweg.pdf is made up also of multiple files that were concatenated with `PDF Arranger`. When clicking on Bildungsweg.pdf, the tab title prints

```
G0-034-F1-20190701130851 - Bildungsweg.pdf
```

Is there **a way to get clean tab titles with no extra text?**

Comment: I would rename the edited PDF files (?)

Comment: Just tried it Johannes. I still get extra text in front of the actual >link text<. I doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the command line `exiftool` after every PDF edition. For example:

```sh
exiftool -Title="" Bildungsweg.pdf
```

Leave the flag `-Title=""` empty, without a string. That way, the web browsers will display the filename instead of the metadata incrusted into the PDF.

Take a look at this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/hubgit/6078384) about anonymising PDFs.

Comment: `apt list "*exiftool*"` lists `ruby-mini-exiftool` and `libimage-exiftool-perl`. Is it one of them, the program you're referring to?

Comment: Ok, I installed `libimage-exiftool-perl` and now I have `man exiftool`

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve the desired result by setting `window.status` but if it’s an external file I’d have a look at the meta properties of the file generated.

My understanding of the way files are prepared by the PDF parser is that this can be problematic but I think this is where you should begin your bug hunt.

In case you embed the file here is the JavaScript:

```
<script type=“text/javascript”>
window.status = ‘hello, world’;
</script>
```